# Showing time labels below Google Charts Timeline

Tags: javascript, charts, google-api, google-visualization, timeline

SOLVED: The timeline chart doesn't play nicely with the bootstrap span class. Debugged in the wrong order and started with code, not markup.

The timeline examples at [Google charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline) all show the timelines with time markers at the bottom. However, I can not get them to appear, and the documentation never mentions them, making me think they were at some point default, but aren't anymore. The examples on the page are all images, so they are not generated by their current API.

Anyone here sorted out this problem before?

EDIT: I should note that a line appears in the markup, hidden and contains something that looks like a single marking, (:10). Also, as requested, here is some of the code. This is a Rails application, and the data for the timeline is fetched via AJAX. Maybe that has something to do with it. The code related to datetime serves the purpose of converting from Ruby to JavaScript format for time. The last line hides a scroll bar that kept showing up:

I have already ruled out problem with the data, because if I switch out my dataTable.addRows() call for the one supplied in the example (same parameters), it still doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
        var rows_for_timeline = [[]];
        var length = 0;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/timelineevents.json',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            data: { operation_id: <%= @op.id %> }, 
            success: function(data){
              rows_for_timeline = data.timeline;
              length = rows_for_timeline.length;
              for(var i = 0; i < rows_for_timeline.length; i++){
                //Convert from ruby to javascript time
                var s_date = new Date(rows_for_timeline[i][2]*1000);
                var e_date = new Date(rows_for_timeline[i][3]*1000);
                rows_for_timeline[i][2] = new Date(s_date.getFullYear(), s_date.getMonth(), s_date.getDate(), s_date.getHours(), s_date.getMinutes(), s_date.getSeconds());
                rows_for_timeline[i][3] = new Date(e_date.getFullYear(), e_date.getMonth(), e_date.getDate(), e_date.getHours(), e_date.getMinutes(), e_date.getSeconds());
                }
              }
        });
        if(length > 0){
            var timeline = $('#timeline')[0];
            var chart;
            chart = null;
            chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(timeline);

            var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Role' });
            dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Name' });
            dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
            dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
            dataTable.addRows(rows_for_timeline);

            var options = {
              timeline: { groupByRowLabel: true }
            };

            chart.draw(dataTable, options);
            //Fix scroll bar at the end.
          $("#timeline").children().first().children().first().children().first().siblings().first().css("overflow-y", "visible");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The Timeline visualization should be showing labels.  If you could provide example code that demonstrates the problem, we can help you figure out why it isn't working for you.

Comment: Code supplied as requested :) I am afraid it might have something to do with the AJAX request. I tested the code in the documentation and it shows the timeline marks.

Comment: SOLVED: The timeline chart doesn't play nicely with the bootstrap span class. Debugged in the wrong order and started with code, not markup.

Thanks for making me improve my debugging process asgallant.